# Cannot install any software through terminal

Tags: linux, installation, vlc-media-player, kali-linux

I'm unable to install any software (like VLC) from the terminal using apt-get. For VLC I wrote:

```
apt-get install VLC.
```

and it gave me output like:

```
root@Akshat:~# apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vlc
```

I have already added required repositories in sources.list:

[image]

My Debian version is Kali Linux Rolling.

Comment: Your sources.list is wrong `www.videolan.org`, also most files there don't seme to be have updated in over a decade.

Answer (score 0):

APT is not able to find a reference to VLC. Run "apt-get update" so it can find the new packages, then apt-get install vlc to install it.

Comment: Already did that, No use